# A verb for having items appended

Tags: single-word-requests

I am proofreading a document and the following sentence came up:

> Unless the data is appended only, then we can assume the temporal sampling has changed.

What the writer is trying to say, is essentially the following:

> Unless the modification made to the data only included appending new data, then we can assume that the temporal sampling has changed.

Is there a verb that I could use to describe the original data set only having data appended to it?

Something along the lines of:

> Unless the data is only (*suffixed*, *verb to describe adding data*, ???)

The way it was written sounds as though the original data was appended to something else.

I hope that the question is clear. If possible I'd prefer a single word, however the most important thing is that the sentence is clear, so if need be I will simply rephrase it.

Comment: 'Unless the data in question is merely added as an appendix, ...' (It would be helpful to give the preceding context specifying _what_ data.)

Comment: Or, *Unless the data is only modified by appending it, we can assume that…* Note that in natural language we don't use *then* following *unless*; see e.g [here](https://www.enago.com/academy/ifthen-using-conditional-sentences-in-academic-writing/).

Comment: I'd be inclined to say "unless the data is only appended to, ...".

Comment: I think your "trying to say" version was pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-order the phrase so that *unless* joins the terms, like this:

> We can assume the the temporal sampling has changed, unless the data is only appended to.

Answer (score 0):

We can assume that the temporal sampling has altered unless the data alteration solely includes adding new data.

Is this alright?

Comment: Or this - Unless the data has been altered purely by appending new data, we can presume that the temporal sampling has changed.